# Three20 TTImageView - How to know when image is loaded from cache and not from remote

Tags: caching, three20

I'm struggling a bit with the TTImageView because of the cache policy.
I cannot just disable the cache.

I'm looking for a way to know if the image displayed is loaded from the local cache or if it has been retrieved from the network.

Is there a way to do so ? WEll I mean there has to be a way somehow.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Check if the image is in the cache like this before you set the url for the TTImageView:

```
UIImage* image = [[TTURLCache sharedCache] imageForURL:URL];
```

if image is not nil it means it is in the cache and will come from the cache if you set the url to a TTImageView